# Affine scheme of matrices with distinct eigenvalues.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I'm learning about affine schemes and want to know if the functor $X : Alg_R \to Sets$ defined such that 
$$X(\mathbf{C}) = \{x \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbf{C}) | x \mbox{ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues}\}$$
where $M_{n \times n}(\mathbf{C})$ denotes the set of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $C$, defines an affine functor.

Thus I'm trying to write it in the form
$$X(\mathbf{C}) = \{ x \in \mathbf{C}^n | f(x)=0, \,  \forall f \in T\}$$
where $T$ defines a set of polynomials on $\mathbf{C}^n$.

I think it should be possible but I can't seem to work out how I could possibly write it like that. Any help would be great!

Comment: I guess you know, but as a subscheme of the $\operatorname{Spec}{Z}[w_{ij}]$, your $X$ is a proper dense subscheme, so it is not a closed subscheme. However, this does not rule out the possibility that it is affine. (For example, complements of hyper surfaces in affine space are affine.) To clarify, you are asking if there is an affine scheme that represents the functor $X$, where $C$ runs over all $R$-algebras?

Comment: Well, it is the complement of a hyper surface, the vanishing hyper surface defined by discriminant of the characteristic polynomial, so that answers your question -- it is affine.

Comment: Ahhh yeah. So currently I have only learned the definition of an affine scheme, and the method used to show that a functor is representable is by showing it can be put in the form of $X(\mathbf{C})$ defined above. So if it is affine, then how would I write it like that?

Comment: The trick is to introduce a new variable $t$ and consider the vanishing of $(Discriminate of Characteristic polynomial)*t = 1$.

Comment: @AreaMan : Correct me if I am wrong but I believe the non-vanishing of the discriminant of a polynomial only implies that there are $n$ distinct roots in an algebraic closure and this also only makes sense if we consider a polynomial over some field (or integral domain).

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I didn't think about that, I think you are right that it makes sense only over a field and I am being sloppy. Still, the polynomials make sense so one can define this affine scheme, but I'm not sure what the interpretation should be for more general rings.